# How can I access a mirror service with userid?

Tags: java, xmpp, google-api-java-client, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I want to receive XMPP message with app engine, and then use a look up table to find the corresponding glass's userid and push timeline cards. I saw the service was created in OAuth. Do I need to create a new service each time? Or I can get the service with userid? Is there any references on service?

### Thanks

This is the code I'm using. Currently I'm creating a new mirror service each time I got a message. Will that cause any trouble or there is a better way to do that? Is there and reference to "util.create_service"?

```
class XmppHandler(xmpp_handlers.CommandHandler):  
    def push_command(self, message=None):
        if message.arg:
            id=XMPP_addr_access.get_id_from_addr(bare_jid(message.sender))
            if id is not None:
                creds=StorageByKeyName(Credentials, id, 'credentials').get()
                mirror_service = util.create_service('mirror', 'v1', creds)
                body = {'notification': {'level': 'DEFAULT'}}
                body['text'] = message.arg
                mirror_service.timeline().insert(body=body).execute()
```

Comment: What do you mean by service? Can you share some code related to the issue you're working on?

Comment: A functional code is attached. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my Glassware, notification responses (what I believe you are calling a service) run similar code to what you have, I generate a new Credential using the java helper method `AuthUtil.getCredential(String userId)` every time I need to make another Mirror API request based on an incoming notification in App Engine.

This credential is used in a `MirrorClient` object that uses the same userId and does the insert back into the timeline.

I get the userId by looking it up in a persisted store referenced by the userToken that the notification provides.